# Core-data: querying distinct entities in many to many relationship with middle entity and condition

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

My core data model is as following:

[image]

where `code` is `NSInteger` in both entities and so is `value`. This maps the following data (sample data, real case scenario is hundreds of rows x hundreds of columns), where columns are `WorkCategories`, `WCn`, rows are `Features`, `Fn` and single cells are `Feasibilities`:

[image]

Given a set of `Features`, I need to retrieve all the distinct `WorkCategories` whose columns has all `Feasibility value`(s) greater than one. `WorkCategories` should also be ordered by their ascending `code`. So:

- If my feature set is `(F1,F3)`, the result should be `(WC3, WC4)`;
- If my feature set is `(F2,F3)`, result should be `(WC1,WC4)`;
- If my feature set is `(F1,F2,F3)`, result should be `(WC4)`.

I achieved it by querying all the `WorkCategories` in Core data and then by filtering them via code using their `feasibility` property.

My question: is there a way to do this in core data using only a single `FetchRequest` (*i.e.*, `executeFetchRequest:error:` output should already be the distinct `WorkCategories` whose columns in the `Feasibility` table has all `value`(s) greater than one)?

Comment: Are WorkCategory-Feature combinations unique? One Feasibility per cell?

Comment: One Feasibility per cell, yes. They are unique, meaning that there's only one Feasibility associated with a pair WCx-Fx (so there is not more than one Feasibility for a given pair) but they are not unique with respect to the Feasibility value, meaning that you could have a pair WCx-Fx with Feasibility value 3 but also a pair WCy-Fy with Feasibility value 3 (in which case, the database would have 2 entries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This predicate for WorkCategories should do it:

`predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(feasibility, $feasibility, $feasibility.value > 1 AND $feasibility.feature IN %@).@count = %lu", featuresSet, (unsigned long)[featuresSet count]`

The subquery gets feasibilities with value > 1 and a feature in the set. If the number of found feasibilities is equal to the number in the set then all feasibilities in the set have a value > 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm! Also, adding a `SortDescriptor` for the `code` property led to ordered `WorkCategories`.